# Why does the input field block after dragging is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a panel named board which has an input field inside and when writing on the input, it shows up in the board. Though, when I drag the board and then try to open another board, the input field gets blocked. I cannot write on it.

```js
function open() {
  const boardIcon = document.querySelector('#board')
  boardIcon.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const board = document.createElement('board')
    board.style.position = 'absolute'
    dragElement(board)
    document.body.appendChild(board)
  })
}
// code copied from w3schools
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0;
  var pos2 = 0;
  var pos3 = 0;
  var pos4 = 0
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + 'header')) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById(elmnt.id + 'header').onmousedown = dragMouseDown
    }, 2000)
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    setTimeout(() => {
      elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown
    }, 2000)
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event
    e.preventDefault()
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX
    pos4 = e.clientY
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event
    e.preventDefault()
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY
    pos3 = e.clientX
    pos4 = e.clientY
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + 'px'
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + 'px'
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null
    document.onmousemove = null
  }
}
```

```css
#board {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background-color: #444;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="addText">
    <input id="write" type="text" placeholder="Write on board..." />
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Send" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML and CSS code too

Comment: @Ramesh do you mind taking a look at it now

Comment: First thing I noticed is you are missing `;` in multiple places in your `js` and the provided `js` not executable since you have them in `functions`, Kindly provide working executable code. You better add a `codepen` or `snippet` with the question.

Comment: I am using standard.js

Comment: If you are using standard js, I noticed few errors in your codeline. Validate your code here https://standardjs.com/demo.html